# Regular expression if else condition

Tags: regex, grafana

I am writing regular expression `[^ ]* ([0-9]+)* [^ ]*` which gets 2nd word / number from a string

Sample input strings:

1. {} **9** 1667986498000
2. {} **19** 1667986498000

From above string Regular expression picks up 9 or 19 which is correct. Now I want regex which checks if the selected number is single digit ? and if yes then it have to preceded with 0. In context with above example 1 output should be 09 instead of 9.

I have tried with below condition

1. If there is single digit match
2. If it is not single digit (may be 2 or more digit)

If it is single digit I wanted to replace that digit with 0 ahead of it e.g. **09**

```
(?:(?=\d{1})0\d|(?!\d{1}).*)
```

I am confused at **0\d**

Comment: You can't match something that isn't there. You'd have to check the number in the match and add zero to it if it's a single digit. What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using this one in Grafana. However even if you suggest something in other language it would be good for me.